# How to extract substrings from a dataframe text column without loop

Tags: r, regex

With a dataframe of string I'm trying to build a new column with the position of a substring.

As regexpr is processing the whole column I built it through a loop. Is there any more clever way to build this column without a loop?

```
abc <- "{\"left\":\"foo\",\"right\":\"no\"},\"answer\":\"left\",\"Id\":258}\""
abb <- "{\"left\":\"foo\",\"up\":\"no\"},\"answer\":\"updownupdwon\",\"Id\":258}\""
df <- data.frame(col=c(abb,abc))
df$pos <- regexpr( "Id\\\":(.*?)}",df$col)
```

My final goal is to get the numerical value (258 here) without writing a loop.

Maybe it's just not possible and I should stay with my loop?

Comment: Just do `as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(df$col, "\\d+"))` or `regmatches(df$col, regexpr( "(?<=Id\\\":)(\\d+)",df$col, perl = TRUE))`

Comment: or `as.numeric(gsub('\\D+', '', df$col))`

Comment: If there are more numbers in the input, use something like [`df$pos <- as.numeric(sub(".*Id\":(\\d+)}.*", "\\1", df$col))`](https://ideone.com/WYbzjX)

Comment: Thanks guys, @Wiktor Stribiżew you made my day. Could you please transform your comment in question so as I can validate it as a good answer? BTW I've tried `gsub` also, but surely did something stupid because it didn't fully worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
df$pos <- as.numeric(sub(".*Id\":(\\d+)}.*", "\\1", df$col))
```

See the [regex online demo](https://regex101.com/r/NtIb6X/1)

**Pattern details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `Id\":` - a `Id":` substring
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern): one or more digits
- `}` - a `}` char
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible (to the end of the string)

See the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/WYbzjX):

```
abc <- "{\"left\":\"foo\",\"right\":\"no\"},\"answer\":\"left\",\"Id\":258}\""
abb <- "{\"left\":\"foo\",\"up\":\"no\"},\"answer\":\"updownupdwon\",\"Id\":258}\""
df <- data.frame(col=c(abb,abc))
df$pos <- as.numeric(sub(".*Id\":(\\d+)}.*", "\\1", df$col))
df
```

Result:

```
                                                          col pos
1 {"left":"foo","up":"no"},"answer":"updownupdwon","Id":258}" 258
2      {"left":"foo","right":"no"},"answer":"left","Id":258}" 258
```